# get element by name not working in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

this is the HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type='text' name='d' value=''><br>(Example: Oct. 8)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Teams:</td><td><input type='text' name='away' value=''> at <input type='text' name='home' value=''><br>(Example: Florida at Buffalo)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Time:</td><td><input type='text' name='t' value=''><br>(Example: 7:00 PM)</td></tr></table><br><input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
```

I am using this code to:

```
Sub extractdata()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim objie As Object
    Set objie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    objie.Top = 0
    objie.Left = 0
    objie.Width = 800
    objie.Height = 600
    objie.Visible = True
    objie.navigate "http://www.dailynhlgoalies.com/loadSchedule.php"

    x = 1

    Dim aloha As String
    Dim aloha1 As String
    Dim aloha2 As String
    Dim aloha3 As String

     aloha = Sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value
    aloha1 = Sheet1.Range("B" & x).Value
    aloha2 = Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value
    aloha3 = Sheet1.Range("D" & x).Value

    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)

    Do
    DoEvents

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objie.Quit
        Set objie = Nothing
        GoTo the_start:
    End If

    Loop Until objie.readyState = 4
        objie.document.getelementbyname("d").Value = aloha
        objie.document.getelementbyname("away").Value = aloha1
        objie.document.getelementbyname("home").Value = aloha2
        objie.document.getelementbyname("t").Value = aloha3
End Sub
```

but it is not working

Comment: <table>
<tr><td>Date:</td><td><input type='text' name='d' value=''><br>(Example: Oct. 8)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Teams:</td><td><input type='text' name='away' value=''> at <input type='text' name='home' value=''><br>(Example: Florida at Buffalo)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Time:</td><td><input type='text' name='t' value=''><br>(Example: 7:00 PM)</td></tr></table><br><input type='submit' value='Submit'>


this is the html code

Comment: Please format (and indent!) your code, and add the HTML to the question.  Comments are not for code or HTML source.  Also, "not working" is not a useful description of your problem.  Do you get an error? If Yes, what is it and on which line?

Comment: [How to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i am getting the run time error 438 when the code reaches 
objie.document.getelementbyname("d").Value = aloha

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the application on the lines

```
objie.Quit
Set objie = Nothing
```

and try to use it later

```
objie.document.getelementbyname("d").Value = aloha
```

you get the error because you closed IE and set the pointer to Nothing

Furthermore, there is no getelementbyname, only getelementSbyname, and it returns a Collection, so you should write:

```
objie.document.getelementsbyname("d")(0).Value = aloha
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `getElementsByName` (note the "s") and it returns a collection of matching elements, not a single element, so you should do something like:

```
 objie.document.getelementsbyname("d")(0).Value = aloha
```

for example