# Not sending the password to IE Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

This was working just fine, and something changed (I suspect the code on the website).  In reviewing all the suggestions of related topics I don't see the same issue I'm having. Let me step you through this:

First, I am using InternetExplorerMedium to address the IE Session -

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://mytargetwebserver.net/reports/views/myMrs/myReports.faces"
```

I then wait for the page to fully load -

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

The next part (passing the password to the IE session is where it is broken. At first I was filling the password field with by ID -

```
IE.Document.getelementbyid(Password).Value = "ThEpAsSwOrD"
```

This method was working perfectly for a long time till something went wonky (I think something changed on the website). When this left the password field blank, I opted to get the element by name instead -

```
IE.Document.getelementbyName("password") = "ThEpAsSwOrD"
```

This proved to be unsuccessful as well.

I went ahead an tried to do a SendKey to simulate typing on the keyboard but that didn't work either.

At this point I'm out of ideas. Suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably a redundant question, but have you checked if the element "Password" still exists on your target website? Can it have been renamed?

Comment: Yes... was the first thing to test the password manually to verify it was still valid and then reinspect the element to verify that nothing had changed.  yeah! This one is goofy!

Comment: Maybe your problem is connected to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-sit)...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948236/get-element-by-name-not-working-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method named getElementByName(), it's name is getElement**s**ByName() and it generates a node collection. Every element has an index like in the other get-methods with *Elements* in the name.

Try the following line:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = "ThEpAsSwOrD"
```

Recently I have also noticed that more and more input fields are tagged with HTML events. You should also check this with the DOM inspector.

Comment: @Zween, my old eyes just didn't catch that... Thank you... it was driving me crazy!